Basic Alpha Beta algorithm giving wrong evaluation
I was in the process of optimizing my chess engine in python when I was doing some testing on this position (engine as black) with a depth of 4:
board and everything seemed fine until I looked at the evaluations for each position. When moving the white pawn from e6 to e7 and then the black queen from h1 to h6, it gives the position a score of 69.5 for black which is clearly wrong because white can promote on the next move.
I rewrote my alpha beta function to its most basic form, like it's written on the chess programming wiki,
Mine:
def search(self, depth: int, whiteTurn: bool, alpha: int, beta: int, baseDepth: int) -> float:
        if depth == 0:
            return self.evaluate(whiteTurn)
        moves = []
        squares = list(self.board.keys())
        # finding legal moves this turn
        if whiteTurn:
            for square in squares:
                # check for a piece
                if self.board[square] != '0' and self.board[square].isupper():
                    squareMoves = self.orderMoves(findLegalMoves(self.pythonBoard.legal_moves, square), square)
                    for move, score in squareMoves:
                        moves.append([ch.Move.from_uci(square + move), score])
            moves = [move[0] for move in sorted(moves, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)]

        else:
            for square in squares:
                if self.board[square] != '0' and self.board[square].islower():
                    squareMoves = self.orderMoves(findLegalMoves(self.pythonBoard.legal_moves, square), square)
                    for move, score in squareMoves:
                        moves.append([ch.Move.from_uci(square + move), score])
            moves = [move[0] for move in sorted(moves, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)]
        for move in moves:
            self.pythonBoard.push(move)
            fenboard = self.pythonBoard.board_fen()
            self.board = fenConverter(fenboard)
            evaluation = -self.search(depth - 1, not whiteTurn, -beta, -alpha, baseDepth)
            if depth == DEPTH:
                print(evaluation, '\n', self.pythonBoard)
            self.pythonBoard.pop()
            self.board = fenConverter(self.pythonBoard.board_fen())
            if evaluation >= beta:
                return beta
            if evaluation > alpha:
                if depth == DEPTH:
                    self.move = move
                    self.materialValue = evaluation
                alpha = evaluation
        return alpha


Their pseudocode:
int alphaBeta( int alpha, int beta, int depthleft ) {
   if( depthleft == 0 ) return quiesce( alpha, beta );
   bestValue = -infinity;
   for ( all moves)  {
      score = -alphaBeta( -beta, -alpha, depthleft - 1 );
      if( score > bestValue )
      {
         bestValue = score;
         if( score > alpha )
            alpha = score; // alpha acts like max in MiniMax
      }
      if( score >= beta )
         return bestValue;   //  fail soft beta-cutoff, existing the loop here is also fine
   }
   return bestValue;
}


with this evaluation function:
def evaluate(self, isWhite: bool) -> float:
        """
        evaluate evaluates the position
        """
        materialValue = 0
        squares = list(self.board.keys())
        if self.pythonBoard.is_stalemate():
            return 0
        if self.pythonBoard.outcome() != None:
            if self.pythonBoard.is_checkmate():
                return float('-inf')

        for square in squares:
            # if there's a piece on the square
            if self.board[square] != '0':
                name = self.board[square]
                color = findColor(name)
                moves = set()
                piece = Piece(name, color, 0, moves)
                if color == 'black':
                    if name == 'p':
                        vMap = pawnMap(square)
                    elif name == 'n':
                        vMap = knightMap(square)
                    elif name == 'b':
                        vMap = bishopMap(square)
                    elif name == 'q':
                        vMap = queenMap(square)
                    elif name == 'k':
                        if ((self.whitePieceCount['Q'] == 0 and self.whitePieceCount['R'] <= 1 and self.whitePieceCount['B'] + self.whitePieceCount['N'] <= 2) or
                            (self.whitePieceCount['B'] + self.whitePieceCount['N'] + self.whitePieceCount['R'] <= 2 and self.whitePieceCount['R'] <= 1)):
                            vMap = lateKingMap(square)
                        else:
                            vMap = earlyKingMap(square)
                    else:
                        vMap = rookMap(square)
                    materialValue += vMap.mapValue()
                if color == 'white':
                    row = int(square[1])
                    newRow = str(9 - row)
                    square = square[0] + newRow
                    if name == 'P':
                        vMap = pawnMap(square)
                    elif name == 'N':
                        vMap = knightMap(square)
                    elif name == 'B':
                        vMap = bishopMap(square)
                    elif name == 'Q':
                        vMap = queenMap(square)
                    elif name == 'K':
                        if ((self.blackPieceCount['q'] == 0 and self.blackPieceCount['r'] <= 1 and self.blackPieceCount['b'] + self.blackPieceCount['n'] <= 2) or
                            (self.blackPieceCount['b'] + self.blackPieceCount['n'] + self.blackPieceCount['r'] <= 2 and self.blackPieceCount['r'] <= 1)):
                            vMap = lateKingMap(square)
                        else:
                            vMap = earlyKingMap(square)
                    else:
                        vMap = rookMap(square)
                    materialValue += -vMap.mapValue()
                materialValue += piece.value * 10
        if isWhite:
            # materialValue += self.endGameEval(self.blackPieces, isWhite)
            return materialValue
        else:
            # materialValue -= self.endGameEval(self.whitePieces, isWhite)
            return -materialValue

Black's piece values are negative and white's are positive, so that's why I return -materialValue for black. In all positions I tested with depth 1 to see if the evaluate function was wrong, it seemed to be working. All the values it gave were expected. I'm unsure how that could be the problem, but then again, I basically copied the function from the chess programming wiki.
Otherwise, the move ordering is fine (shouldn't affect the evaluation either way) and it finds all possible moves correctly.
Today I tested the program without any pruning and it worked, so now I'm sure that the problem is in the pruning. I'm really confused because I rewrote the function again, exactly like in the wiki, and at that point, the wrong evaluations started popping up again.

I think that I've finally found the problem because everything seems fine now that I've added this line of code:
if evaluation == alpha and depth == baseDepth:
    continue

Every time a bad move had a good score, it had the same score as the first, top-engine move. When pruning branches, the bad positions were just given the same score, which is not what I wanted. For example, if the best move was given a score of 80, every other bad move also had a score of 80.
